# Complexity and Efficiency in Algorithm for: a[j]-a[i] i>=j

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I'm looking to make this much quicker. I've contemplated using a tree, but I'm not sure if that would actually help much.

I feel like the problem is for most cases you don't need to calculate all the possible maximums only a hand full, but I'm not sure where to draw the line

Thanks so much for the input, 
Jasper

```
public class SpecialMax {

    //initialized to the lowest possible value of j; 
    public static int jdex = 0; 
    //initialized to the highest possible value of i; 
    public static int idex; 
    //will hold possible maximums 
    public static Stack<Integer> possibleMaxs = new Stack<Integer> (); 

    public static int calculate (int[] a){
        if (isPositive(a)){ 
            int size = a.length; 
            int counterJ; 
            counterJ = size-1;

            //find and return an ordered version of a

            int [] ordered = orderBySize (a);

            while (counterJ>0){
                /* The first time this function is called, the Jvalue will be 
                 * the largest it can be, similarly, the Ivalue that is found
                 * is the smallest
                 */
                int jVal  = ordered[counterJ];  
                int iVal  = test (a, jVal);
                possibleMaxs.push(jVal-iVal);
                counterJ--; 
            }

            int answer = possibleMaxs.pop(); 

            while (!possibleMaxs.empty()){
                if (answer<possibleMaxs.peek()){
                    answer = possibleMaxs.pop(); 
                } else { 
                    possibleMaxs.pop(); 
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The maximum of a[j]-a[i] with j>=i is: ");
            return answer;
        } else {
            System.out.println ("Invalid input, array must be positive"); 
            return 0; //error
        }
    }

    //Check to make sure the array contains positive numbers
    public static boolean isPositive(int[] a){ 
        boolean positive = true; 
        int size = a.length; 

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            if (a[i]<0){
                positive = false; 
                break; 
            }
        }


        return positive; 
    }

    public static int[] orderBySize (int[] a){
         //orders the array into ascending order
         int [] answer = a.clone(); 
         Arrays.sort(answer);
         return answer; 
    }

         /*Test returns an Ival to match the input Jval it accounts for 
          * the fact that jdex<idex. 
          */
    public static int test (int[] a, int jVal){
        int size = a.length;
        //initialized to highest possible value
        int tempMin = jVal; 
        //keeps a running tally 
        Stack<Integer> mIndices = new Stack<Integer> (); 

        //finds the index of the jVal being tested
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) { 
            if (jVal==a[i]){
                //finds the highest index for instance
                if (jdex<i){
                    jdex = i;
                }
            }
        }

        //look for the optimal minimal below jdex;  
        for (int i=0; i<jdex; i++){
            if (a[i]<tempMin){
                tempMin = a[i]; 
                mIndices.push(i);
            }
        }

        //returns the index of the last min
        if (!mIndices.empty()){
           idex = mIndices.pop(); 
        }

        return tempMin; 
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: I can't figure out the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but still it's a good idea to put it in the body of the question, not just in the subject.

Comment: Question is still unclear, add something about finding the maximum to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in linear time and linear memory. The idea is: find the minimum over each suffix of the array and maximum over each prefix, then find the point where the difference between the two is the highest. You'll also have to store the index on which the maximum/minimum for each prefix is reached if you need the indices, rather than just the difference value.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-sorting a[] makes the procedure complicated and impairs performance. It is not necessary, so we leave a[] unsorted.

Then (EDITED, because I had read j>=i in the body of your code, rather than i>=j in the problem description/title, which I now assume is what is required (I didn't go over your coding details); The two varieties can easily be derived from each other anyway.)

```
// initialize result(indices)
int iFound = 0;
int jFound = 0;
// initialize a candidate that MAY replace jFound
int jAlternative = -1; // -1 signals: no candidate currently available

// process the (remaining) elements of the array - skip #0: we've already handled that one at the initialization
for (int i=1; i<size; i++)
{
  // if we have an alternative, see if that combines with the current element to a higher "max".
  if ((jAlternative != -1)  && (a[jAlternative]-a[i] > a[jFound]-a[iFound]))
  {
    jFound = jAlternative;
    iFound = i;
    jAlternative = -1;
  }
  else if (a[i] < a[iFound]) // then we can set a[iFound] lower, thereby increasing "max"
  {
    iFound = i;
  }
  else if (a[i] > a[jFound])
  { // we cannot directly replace jFound, because of the condition iFound>=jFound,
    // but when we later may find a lower a[i], then it can jump in:
    // set it as a waiting candidate (replacing an existing one if the new one is more promising).
    if ((jAlternative = -1) || (a[i] > a[jAlternative]))
    {
      jAlternative = i;
    }
  }
}

double result = a[jFound] - a[iFound];
```